# What am I missing here, the Self powers problem on Project euler

Tags: python

**Question: The series, 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + 10^10 = 10405071317. Find the last ten digits of the series, 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + 1000^1000.**

My code was

```
sum=0
for x in range(1001):
    k=x**x
    sum=sum+k
print(sum)
```

Yet the answer was wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: what makes you think that the terms of this series are given by `x*x`?

Comment: sorry @Ma0, it was x**x, and my answer's still wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your program gives a huge number. You need to return the last 10 digits so replace `print(sum)` with `print(sum%10**10)`.

Also the problem starts from 1 but you are starting from 0. replace the loop with `range(1, 1001)` since 0^0=1 so your answer will be off by one.

Comment: Thanks! Consider accepting the answer if you think it solved your problem.